# Catch throw error from node module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using a module which throws an error in case something is wrong. The error is not being returned as part of the callback and the run is being stopped when is thrown.

I am calling it like this:

```
co(function*(){
  try{
    for (let item of items){
       item.newValue = yield myFunction(param)
    }
  }catch(err){
  }
}

myFunction: function(param){
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
   module.callMethod(param), function(result){
     if (result)
         resolve(result)  
  }else{
      reject('err')}
}
}
```

During callMethod I get a throw error but it is not caught on the `co` `try` and I'd like in case of a error to catch it but allow the `for` loop to continue.

How can I properly catch the thrown error?

Comment: You aren't using `async`, so you're never actually consuming that promise.

Comment: I am using `yield`

Comment: `yield` has nothing to do with promises.

Comment: I don't understand, the code actually works when the module does not throw an error. Error is thrown depending on the param value...

Comment: Is `module.callMethod` calling the callback synchronously or asynchronously?

Comment: `yield myFunction(param).catch(console.error)`

Comment: @trincot I don't know, the module is not open source...

Comment: you can not simply `catch` it when using `yield` and `co`. you can `co(...).catch(e => console.log(e))`

Comment: @Jonasw s not working

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ but I need to be able to have the for loop running in case of thrown error and not break the execution.

Comment: What do you expect `result` to be? As it stands, you're just overwriting it.

Comment: @trincot it was just a sample code, I've updated it so I set the value of the item on each new call

Comment: OK, but now the question remains: what do you expect `item.newValue` to be: the promise or the promised value (i.e. `result`)?

Comment: well, you should handle the `throw`n error in the `myFunction` yourself using `try`/`catch`. the rest are promises, and promises should handle errors with rejecting the promise. rejecting the promise would result in an error thrown which you can catch (like you already do) in your `co` function.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like in case of a error to catch it but allow the for loop to
>   continue

`Promise` constructor should treat errors thrown inside executor as promise rejection.

> [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) If an error is thrown in the executor function, the promise is
>   rejected.

So moving `try-catch` inside for loop should work. 
.

```js
'use strict'
co(function*() {
  for (let item of [1, 2, 3, 4]) {
    try {
      const newValue = yield myFunction(item)
      console.log(newValue)
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e.message)
    }
  }
})

function callMethod(param, cb) {
  if (param % 2) cb('Success')

  throw new Error(`Invalid param ${param}`)
}

function myFunction(param) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    callMethod(param, function(result) {
      if (result) {
        resolve(result)
      } else {
        reject('err')
      }
    })
  })
}
```

```html
<script>
  const module = {}
</script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/co@4.6.0/index.js"></script>
```

Comment: but, if `callMethod` was a true async function, it doesn't handle the exception. I mean, put the whole body of the function inside a `setTimeout`.

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ Then nothing much you could do, I guess.